# Building a stationary robot which can talk

Tags: sensors, communication, first-robotics, speech-processing

I am a Computer Science major and I only have basic ideas on Robotics. I am planning to build a stationary cubical AI.

The main purpose of this bot will be that, it will have a sensor to check if the door has been opened and immediately asks a question "who has opened the door?" I also want it to recognize the correct words to interact the word, I am not talking about voice recognition but word recognition so that who ever speaks the correct words(words in bot's memory) can interact with it. Depending on who opens the door(prolly my family) I want it to speak out different things. I want it to respond to simple questions like, "what is the date and time?" , " a random qoute or a fact or a joke".

Is this too hard to achieve? Could anyone give me a basic idea on how to approach this project?

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics*, Saujan Uprety. As your project doesn't pertain to robotics (beyond being an object people interact with), and instead appears to be a strictly software-related question, I voted to move it from this site to one where you would be more likely to get a proper answer, like Computer Science. Topics like speech recognition are beyond the scope of this site.

Comment: Cross-posted on CS.SE: http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/54761/755. Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.

Comment: Hey @Chuck, may I make a suggestion? If you're going to suggest another site, it'd help to tell people not to cross-post: suggest that they delete this copy and post it elsewhere.  Cross-posting is forbidden, and suggesting people post it elsewhere just leads them down a path that will have an unsatisfying experience.  Also, it's probably best to be careful about recommending a site that you're not active with. [This question seems a bit broad/unfocused for CS.SE in its current form](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/54761/building-a-door-sensor-ai?noredirect=1#comment115222_54761).

Comment: @D.W. - When I consider whether a question is suitable for this site or should be moved to another, I try to ignore how qualitatively good/bad the question is. This is specifically because, as you point out, I am *not* active with the CS.SE. That is, I don't know what *would* qualify as a good or bad question for your site; what is too broad or isn't, etc. I know that, by voting to move it, I'm voting to *close* it on this site.

Comment: Only questions about Robotics Stack Exchange should be migrated to meta.

Answer (score -1):

> Is this too hard to achieve?

No

> Could anyone give me a basic idea on how to approach this project?

Get familiar with the basics and start writing code. Here are few links for you to study:

[Robot operating system](http://ros.org)

[CMUSphinx in ROS](http://wiki.ros.org/pocketsphinx)

Try to follow the examples as is first, that will give you a basic understaning, then you can extend the example to fit your needs.